# processing 3.0 - P3D - axis rotated - new coordinates of the rectangles?

Tags: graph, processing, visualization, data-visualization

I am using processing 3.0 - P3D and I have a collection of rectangles. The axes were rotated to get a 3d view.

```java
rotateX(PI / 4);
rotateZ(PI / 10);
//I didn't rotate Y axis
```

Hows can I get the new x-coordinate and Y-coordinate of the rectangles? so that I can use those coordinates to match with the mouse click point.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `screenX()` and `screenY()` functions.

```java
rotateX(PI / 4);
rotateZ(PI / 10);
rect(modelX, modelY, rectWidth, rectHeight);

float viewX = screenX(modelX, modelY);
float viewY = screenY(modelX, modelY);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/screenX_.html).